# Magento: Adding contacts form to footer

Tags: php, xml, forms, magento, footer

I am quite new to Magento, and I'm trying to echo the built in contact form in the footer of a custom Magento-theme.
It can't get it working, this is my code:

Path to form.phtml: (app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/contacts/form.phtml)

XML (app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/page.xml:

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
        <label>Page Footer</label>
        <action method="setElementClass">
            <value>bottom-container</value>
        </action>
    </block>
    <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
    <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
    <block type="contacts/form" name="form" as="form" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
    //the contact form
    <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
    <block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_contact">
        <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>contact_info</block_id>
        </action>
    </block>
</block>
```

php (app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/page/html/footer.phtml):

```
 <div class="footer">
    <div class="col3-set">
        <div class="col-1">
            <div class="footer-links">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cms_footer_links') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_links') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <h2 class="<footer-title"><?php echo $this->__('Ask us') ?></h2>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('contact-form') ?>
          <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form') ?> //echoing the form
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <h2 class="footer-title"><?php echo $this->__('Contact Details') ?></h2>
            <div class="footer-contacts">
                <?php
                    if(Mage::getStoreConfig("trego_settings/footer/newsletter", $code)){
                        echo $this->getChildHtml('newsletter');
                    }
                ?>
                <div class="contact-info">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cms_footer_contact') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-menu">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_socialIcons'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_copyrights'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm also quite new to Magento. But when I have a Magento related question, I post it over at: https://magento.stackexchange.com/ - It might take a little bit longer to get an answer, however the answers are normally much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `core/template` as block type. Therefore change:

```
<block type="contacts/form" name="form" as="form" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
```

to

```
<block type="core/template" name="form" as="form" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why that block-type should be used instead of the other? Is the other not a valid block type any longer?

Comment: Thats the block that Magento uses for contact form: `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php`.

Comment: Cheers, this really did it!

Answer (score 1):

If you are warred `about xml code then paste` the below code in footer.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("core/template")->setTemplate("contacts/form.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

and after that goto form.phtml change the action of form to `$this->getUrl('contacts/index/post');`
There are not need of xml

More details http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/contact-form-in-magento/

Answer (score -2):

Try to do this on your own. Use e. g. Contact Form 7 plugin, create your form and insert the shortcode provided by CF7 into a text widget.